# Minimum Distance

Tags: algorithm

There is a set of 9 students and 3 schools Every school can be alloted at max 3 students .Every school and student has its coordinates .Now we have to allot student in such a way that the sum of distance from all the student to the school should be minimum.

I was asked this question in an interview.Can anyone suggest an algorithm for this?

Initially I tried greedy approach but that does not work.Then I tried applying a dynamic programming approach but could not come up with an optimal sub-structure.

Comment: The problem at hand is called bipartite graph matching

Comment: Can you suggest some good reading material on bipartite graph matching.

Comment: This book is good but probably too theoretic: ["Matching Theory" by M.D. Plummer, L. Lovász](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Matching_Theory.html?id=mycZP-J344wC&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 4):

Every school has 3 places, all 3 schools have 9 places. And you should find the best match between 9 places and 9 students.

This assignment problem may be solved with [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

How about exhaustive search since the problem size is small enough?

- First school chooses 3 students out of 9 to start.
- Second school chooses 3 students out of 6 remaining.
- Last school gets stuck with the 3 students remaining.

So `(9 choose 3) * (6 choose 3) = 1680`

Comment: I am looking for an efficient solution.